# Weird behavior in Ruby (on Rails) using Array#find

Tags: ruby, arrays, find, block

Take a good look at the snippet below:

```
a = [1,2,3]
n = 2
puts a.find { |i| i == n }
=> 2

a = [1,2,3]
n = [2]
puts a.find { |i| i == n.shift }
=> nil
```

Tip: you can see a running version here http://repl.it/OL3

Now explain it. Why the second `#find` returns `nil` ?

Comment: to avoid the problem use `path.dup.shift`

Comment: @majioa That's completely nuts. Just use `path[-1]` or `path.last`.

Comment: @tadman probably asker wish to use `#shift`

Comment: The snippet is out of context. In the context `shift` does make sense.

Comment: Use `f.elements.find {|e| e['name'] == path[0]}`

Comment: Please don't put running commentary and replies to comments in your question. Think of your question like an article in Wikipedia; You're asking, others are answering, all to provide a reference on how to deal with the problem you've encountered. Also, the code you reference needs to be IN your question, not on another site, which includes your "repl.it" sample. If that link breaks, your question becomes nonsense. It's OK to modify your question to clarify and add additional examples, just remember it's not a conversation.

Comment: I'll rectify the commentary, thanks. But all the code is IN my question. The link is a supporting it so you - while it works - see a running version of the sample, otherwise you can run it yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [`Array#shift`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-shift) removes the element from the array.

So, the first time the block executes, it is comparing `e['name'] == "pets"` but on the next iteration, it is comparing `e['name'] == nil`. Unless `e['name']` is `"pets"` on the first iteration, the `.find` will return `nil`.

Comment: I think the snippet isn't obvious enough, but that is not the case. You see, I assign a new value to `path` both times right before i execute `#find`. First I set it to a string `'pets'` then I set it to an array with a string `['pets']`. You can even note the lines `irb` is mentioning: 86 is where I set path, 87 is where I call #find.

Comment: Always be aware of methods that do in-place modification of the object they're called on. Many are identified with `!` but there are some like `shift` that pre-date that convention.

Comment: You both are not paying attention. I DO know that `shift` mutates the variable. But that is NOT the case.

Comment: @ArthurCorenzan `.find` executes the code in the block once for every element in `f.elements`. So, if there are 3 elements, your block gets called 3 times. Hence, `.shift` gets called on the array 3 times. The first time reduces the array to `[]`.

Comment: Maybe you need to amend your question with a more generic example because I'm in complete agreement with @CharlesCaldwell here.

Comment: I see the edited question but my original answer still applies.

Comment: Holy cow, now I see it. So sorry buddy!

Answer (score 0):

*@Charles Caldwell* explained correctly, why you did get that result. Now just use [`Array#first`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-first) method as below which is safe :

```
a.find { |i| i == n.first }
```